# How does someone become a contractor in Kaze no Stigma?

Tags: kaze-no-stigma

A contractor is someone who makes a deal with a Spirit Lord and gains a large amount of strength from it. Kazuma became a contractor with the Kaze no Seirei-Ō. Is it ever shown how he becomes the contractor, and is the way that a wind-user becomes a contractor the same as the way that another spirit user becomes a contractor? If there are manga images that explain it, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It is never explained how Kazuma became a Contractor, and the process would´ve likely been covered had the writer not died. The best guess I can give is that:

1. He had incredible magical potential, just not when it comes to fire.
2. He was in desperate need for the power and made an earnest wish to the Wind Spirit King, catching his interest.